# Windows Task Scheduler: Can I export (save) my tasks?

Tags: export, import, windows-task-scheduler

I've setup a dozens of tasks on the Windows Task Scheduler. Everything is working fine but now I am concerned about being able to re-create these tasks if the PC needs to be replaced. The problem is that I have the timing staggered for these tasks and it would be really tedious to have to create each one all over again.

Is there a way to "export" my tasks and "import" them on another PC?

If it makes any difference, I am working on windows XP.
BTW, if I can export/import, will it work across XP and windows 7?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP stores the Scheduled Tasks as `*.job` files, so navigate to the folder and copy them. You should be able to import them by simply double-clicking on each one in the newer Windows. You may need to reset authentication on them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Copying and running .job files will suffice on another XP machine, however they won't work on Vista/Win7 because scheduled tasks are stored as .xml files and can only be imported that way.

Additionaly, as they point out [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistamigration/thread/76b6276b-49f2-41e2-b4ea-f537e0eb88a8), there is no way to convert .job files to xml. Nevertheless, in that topic a script is suggested as a solution to ease the migration process. You might want to try it out if you're planning to move to Win7.